# How to find out the class of a React.ComponentType?

Tags: typescript

Here is an example typescript code:

```
export class EditorController {
  constructor(
      private readonly DocumentView: React.ComponentType<{ page: Page }>,
  ) {
       /* some initialisation */
  },
```

The `EditorController` can be initiated with different implementation of `DocumentView`  class at various points in my app. I would like to find out what get injected to the constructor, preferably the class name.

Currently if I just print out the variable this is what I got:

```
function _class() {
                classCallCheck(this, _class);
                return possibleConstructorReturn(this, (_class.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(_class)).apply(this, arguments));
            }
```

Comment: I'm looking for something similar. I have "export function withSomething<P>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>): React.ComponentClass<P> {// How to get class name of the wrapped Component here?}"